# Symfony access parameter by tree path

Tags: symfony, yaml

I try to do something, maybe simple but I can't find how to do !

My yml file is like this :

```
parameters:
    mykey1:
        mykey2:
            mykey3: value
```

I want to use it in my services like "%mykey1.mykey2.mykey3%" but got a message telling that "mykey1.mykey2.mykey3" does not exists...
I have to use "%mykey1%" and in php use $mykey['mykey2']['mykey3'].

Or I have to write my parameters in flat mode like this but I don't like this because I have a lot of things in my parameters in many levels...

```
parameters:
    mykey1.mykey2.mykey3 : value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters are simple key-value stores. They don't support nesting in any way. It's also not what they should support, that's not something parameters should fix.

Instead, you're probably looking to add custom configuration for your bundle (or app). This configuration is then transformed into parameters during container compilation. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html for more information about this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it